# Fiddler and Windows Phone 7 emulator - redirect to proxy

Tags: proxy, windows-phone-7, fiddler, wireshark

I am just curious - did anyone got **Fiddler** to work with Windows Phone 7 emulator (RTW build)? When I try working with Fiddler, I am getting a **WebException** when working with **HttpWebRequest** insances - **NotFound**, to be specific. **WireShark** works fine.

The problem I see here is that **Fiddler** acts as a proxy and the WP7 application I am using doesn't go through a proxy to pass the request, while **WireShark** works differently - it doesn't directly pass traffic through it.

There was a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305018/using-fiddler-to-debug-the-windows-phone-7-emulator) but in my case I would like to override the proxy settings so that the WP7 application will connect to **http:/127.0.0.1:8888** as the proxy address. Since WP7 tools are based on Silverlight, is it possible to direct a **HttpWebRequest** to a proxy first?

**EDIT:** On [this page](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp) (Fiddler documentation) it is stated that XDE (Windows Phone 7 emulator) should automatically pick up system proxy settings, but for some reason it seems like it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a temporary workaround for this, you can set Fiddler as a reverse proxy. The process is described [here](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/Help/ReverseProxy.asp). I used the second option by creating a rule.

**NOTE:** You **have to** set the initial host (in the *if* statement) to the Fiddler proxy location (since the WP7 emulator can see the proxy address). The second URL is the address you want to redirect to.

It will now capture traffic from Windows Phone 7 emulator, although it will still skip some things (like downloaded images), so use this method for testing purposes only.

Comment: It took me 3 hours at night to get it working. On my machine it turns out I shouldn't have tried the actual MachineName, but to use localhost:8888 localhost:80 pair.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the very simple solution that worked for me: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151102011256/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/fiddler/archive/2010/10/15/fiddler-and-the-windows-phone-emulator.aspx)